# How to configure GIT HTTPS client certificate authentication in Eclipse using EGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, https, egit, client-certificates

I set up a GIT server (Gitblit) that uses HTTPS client authentication. I have a working configuration and key material with the standard GIT client on Linux (Debian).

Until now I didn't figure out how to correctly configure:

- The standard GIT client (command line, v1.9.5) on Windows (Win7 64)
- Eclipse (Luna) with EGit.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use SSH? It's very common and, I guess, just as secure.

Comment: This question is very broad, and a detailed answer would be too long for one question.  But this link will help you get started with the Git client: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup .  Egit is another story and I recommend mastering the command line BEFORE you switch to the GUI.

Comment: @As I said in the question, it works with the standard (command line) Git client on Debian. I know how to do that, so this question is not about "getting started with the Git client" but specifically about the Git client on Windows - which appearently behaves different in this case and the EGit component/plugin in Eclipse which obviously is configured in a completely different way than any command line client.

Comment: @musiKk: GitBlit is part of a bigger infrastructure that includes a security and authentication framework. Currently this framework includes policies, audits etc. for HTTPS. Extending it to cover SSH would be possible, but expensive. Missing knowledge about how to use Git over HTTPS would not be an acceptable reason to justify those expenses.

Comment: @Gustave For JGit it seems this has been [implemented but never merged](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/3199/1). Windows I don't know but the official builds are way behind current versions. Maybe you need to compile a newer version.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 7, I successfully used these parameters:

```
[http "https://git.repository.net"]
proxy = proxy.to.use:1234
sslCert = "C:/Path/to/mycert.crt"
sslKey = "C:/Path/to/mycert.key"
sslVerify = true
sslCertPasswordProtected = false
```

Be sure to not forget the quotes, or you will run into trouble with forward slashes.
I think git will also prompt you for the password, if you leave one on the key, but I'm not sure how well it can cache, and for me it got old quick to re-enter that password routinely.

Regarding Eclipse: I can at least verify, that the current SimRel 2018-9 doesn't work with that .gitconfig, so I'm still looking for a way to make it work.